# How do I solve this double summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} (i+1)$$

Not totally sure how to get passed this one.  I brought it down from a triple to a double, but I'm having trouble with the fact that $i$ is the what is being added.

My thought is that it will be$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^2,$$ but I cannot say that with total certainty.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your summation is not well defined. Notice that the outside summation index starts at $i = 0$, but the inside summation is defined from $j = 0$ to $j = i - 1$, which in this case would mean the summation indexes from $0$ to $-1$, which is meaningless as far as I know.

Comment: ok, is there a closed form formula for something like that?

Comment: I'm doing algorithm analysis for a computer science class.I guess that doesn't really make much sense.  I can just change a couple of variables here and there to make the loops run from j=1 to i, instead of j=0 to <i

Comment: @Kurtis: the convention is that empty sums (that is, lower index > upper index) are zero. So the formula's actually quite fine.

Comment: @J.M. I'm aware that is the convention. "Meaningless" was a poor choice of wording on my part. My intention was just to ensure that there wasn't a typo or anything mixed in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} (i+1)$

is composed of tow sums. Let's figure the inner sum first:

$\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} (i+1) = (i+1)(i-1-0+1) = (i+1)(i)$

Now you can evaluate the outer sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)(i)$ which is: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2+i$

You can split the summs as:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2$ + $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i$

The following link may help you further:
[Some summations of polynomial expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there some sort of closed form formula for something like that?

Comment: @MichaelSchilling, What do you mean by closed form formula?

Comment: Or one like this: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2$

Comment: Maybe that the wrong terminology. How $\sum_{i=0}^{n}$ i   = (n(n+1))/2

Comment: @MichaelSchilling, if you check the link at the end of the post, you will find the formula for summing $i^2$

Comment: Oh, ok. What about the $i^2 + i$ one though? Is it possible to spit those up into two summations?

EDIT: ok, nevermind. I got it. thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I edited to post to show that.